# Installing Java on EC2 Instance -- Unzip error

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, tar, unzip

I've been trying to install java for a while now on my EC2 instance and I'm having no luck.

I keep getting the error:

```
    sudo tar xf jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz 

    gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
    tar: Child returned status 1
    tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I cannot get this to work with ZXF or XF..

I have tried renaming it to .tar but then I get this does not look like a tar archive..

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**I am running a 64 bit instance

```
FILE jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz 
jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

My checksum is bad...

```
81ee08846975d4b8d46acf3b6eddf103  jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Should be (by oracle.com):

```
dk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz    764f96c4b078b80adaa5983e75470ff2
```

How do I fix this? I've tried re-downloading and it has not fixed the problem. I also get the wrong sum when trying to download the 32 bit version.

WGET is not downloading the file correctly. So I'm going to look into that. If anyone has an idea before I find it, it will of course be much appreciated. -- It's downloading a text file (of HTML ).

Comment: Please add the output of `file jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz` to your question.

Comment: I downloaded the file with wget -- copy pasting the address from my computer into SSH terminal. Perhaps it's corrupted? Or not the correct file?

Comment: My checksum is bad...

Comment: Why not use the command `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` this will install java for you.

Comment: I'm trying to set up cassandra on the server and it's recommended to use Oracle's JRE (maybe even required?).

Comment: NEVER install an application when the checksum doesn't match!

Comment: It's an HTML file, quite likely an error page or something like that. Go to http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp and get the file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just had the same issue, turns out one has to accept oracles license areement in order to download. doing so sets a cookie, which in turn will allow one to download the .tar.gz. without that cookie, oracle redirects the request to a html site. ("please sign our license agreement yadda yadda...")

wget will download this html, instead of the archive, because it lacks the auth coockie.

solution: download it using a webbrowser, then scp it to wherever you need it.